# Unsuitable PythonLibs building catkin (Mac OS X 10.9.3)

Tags: ros, python, catkin, ros-hydro, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am trying to install ROS hydro (desktop full version) on a MacBook Pro with Mavericks (10.9.3). When I build the catkin workspace I get the following error:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/203daa1de0b89bf37c6fe95312532c4d

The gcc version is:

```
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

It seems that the PythonLibs is outdated, but running the command

```
python --v
```

I get

```
Python 2.7.8
```

Some can help me?

Thank you,
Andrea

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187042/unsuitable-pythonlibs-building-catkin-(mac-os-x-10.9.3)/) by [-Andrew-](https://answers.ros.org/users/9051/-andrew-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you installed python from homebrew. There are issues with cmake and brewed python, i.e. cmake pickes up the library provided by Apple (version 2.7.5), but the python interpreter is the one from homebrew 2.7.8. Hence the error. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25118 for a long unresolved discussion of this problem.

You should be able to address this with a patched (but experimental!) version of the Python cmake modules:

```
brew remove cmake; brew install nikolausdemmel/devel/cmake
```

Then remove the `build*` and `devel*` folders and retry the compilation.

On a side note, you are aware of the other patches currently needed to build Hydro `desktop_full` on OS X 10.9? You will likely need to apply the following patches in your workspace (see https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4663):

```
pushd src/robot_model
curl https://github.com/ros/robot_model/pull/43.patch | patch -p1
popd
```

```
pushd src/robot_state_publisher
curl https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/5.patch | patch -p1
popd
 
pushd src/python_qt_binding/
curl https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/pull/12.patch | patch -p1
popd
```

**Update:** Of the above three patches, only the robot_model patch is needed, and even that should be released soon.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [-Andrew-](https://answers.ros.org/users/9051/-andrew-/) on 2014-07-19**:
It worked perfectly! Thank you demmmeln! Thank you also for the note, I did not known nothing about the patches.